# How can I update all the records that match my SELECT query in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to change the **post_status** field for all the records from February 2017 in a particular table to *wc-pending*

I have figured out how to select all those records:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%FEB%2017%'
```

And I *think* this will change the field as I need to:

```
SET post_status='wc-pending'
```

But I am stumped on how to put these two together to update the post_status fields for only those records that match the SELECT query.

My hunch is that the following might do it if I execute it while in that table

```
SET post_status='wc-pending' WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%FEB%2017%'
```

Does that seem correct?
Any guidance is appreciated. I am totally new to SQL. Thanks!

Comment: instead of thinking and using your hunch, the best, most efficient and reliable way is to look up the MySQL docs. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status='wc-pending' WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%FEB%2017%'
```

You can even do more complex stuff, like add some inner joins. By the way, there's a way in phpmyadmin to simulate the query, see how it turns out.

Comment: Fantastic! I just had to add ` ` around wp_posts but then it worked perfectly. The UPDATE command was new to me, thanks so much for your help! That just saved me about 8 hours of button pushing in Wordpress